# Collada skinning

Tags: c++, c

I hope you can help me. My problem is with the collada's skinning equation:

```
v += {[(v * BSM) * IBMi * JMi] * JW}
```

- `n`: The number of joints that influence vertex v
- `BSM`: Bind-shape matrix
- `IBMi`: Inverse bind-pose matrix of joint i
- `JMi`: Transformation matrix of joint i
- `JW`: Weight of the influence of joint i on vertex v

Each vertex "v" must be calculated (i.e. through a "for" bucle). But, it`s not very, very slow if I have a mesh of 10,000 vertices or more? This must be calculated ever in real time? No other way to calculate "v"?

Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use a threshold `JW` - for each vertex `v`, you may skip further computation for any joint `i` on `v` where `JWi` is below some threshold.

Also you could precompute `IBMi * JMi` for each joint once, right?